# Using jetty plus in equinox jetty bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jaas, embedded-jetty

We are trying to get JAAS working in our RAP application. We run jetty through the equinox jetty bundle and configure it with a fragment which contains a jettycustomizer class.

Now we want to use jetty-plus for JAAS but when I try to add the dependency to the fragment it gives the following error:

!MESSAGE Constraints from the fragment conflict with the host: Require-Bundle: org.mortbay.jetty.plus; bundle-version="6.1.23"

Does anybody know how to fix this, or add JAAS an other way. Because this is so frustrating. Thanks